# Images not loading when add height or width to the HTML " img src" Option

Tags: java, html

When height is there images don't load up. When I remove height images load perfectly with original image size. I just need to show images to fixed size in the web page. Why can't I use height and width in this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Listing Images</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Listing Images</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Preview</th>
            <th>Available information</th>
            <th>Update Information</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <%
                List<Files> files = (List<Files>) request.getAttribute("files");
                String path = (String) request.getAttribute("path");
                for (Files file : files) {
                out.print("<tr><td><img src="+ path+file.getFileName()+"height='200'></td></tr>");}
            %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try adding space between `+"` and `height`? something like this `<img src="+ path+file.getFileName()+" height='200'>`. Not sure if that's the problem, but you can give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the escape character `\"` in your `out.print()` statement where the `src=` tag is

I would try this `out.print("<tr><td><img src=\""+ path+file.getFileName()+"\"height='200'></td></tr>");`

Comment: wow, that works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @ThilinaPalamakumbura no problem